# C++ Object Creation & Lists

Tags: c++, list, initialization

Main Method -> contains a list of Family objects. Family -> contains a list of Person objects.

Upon creation of a Family object, how do I force it to create a new list of ‘Person’ objects for every new instance of Family??

Currently all Family objects in the main list are sharing the one Linked list of Person..

Would appreciate your thoughts. I have to use a linked list of linked lists...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Family
{
private:
   int family_id;

public:
   int getFamilyId();
   void createPerson(int id, string name);
   void readPersonName();

   Family(int id);
   ~Family();
};

list <Person> people;

Family::Family(int id)
{
   family_id = id;
}

Family::~Family(void){};



int Family::getFamilyId()
{
   return family_id;
};


void Family::createPerson(int id, string name)
{
   people.push_back(Person(id, name));
};


void Family::readPersonName()
{
   list<Person>::iterator itr;
   for(itr = people.begin(); itr != people.end(); itr++)
      cout << itr->get_person_name() << '\n';
};
```

Comment: Just add the list in your class, not in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Upon creation of a Family object, how do I force it to create a new list of ‘Person’ objects for every new instance of Family??"*

Why don't you simply declare that list as a class member?

```
class Family {
private:
   int family_id;

public:
   int getFamilyId();
   void createPerson(int id, string name);
   void readPersonName();

   Family(int id);
   ~Family();
private:
   list <Person> people; // <<<<<
};
```

> *"I have to use a linked list of linked lists..."*

I don't fully understand this part of your question. Do you need to keep a global list for all persons as well?

In this case you should use lists of shared objects of persons:

```
class Family {
// ....
   void createPerson(int id, string name) {
        people.push_back(new Person(id,name));
        allPeople.push_back(people.back());
   }
private:
   list <shared_ptr<Person>> people;
};

list<shared_ptr<Person>> allPeaople;
```

Comment: With this solution, you duplicate the Person instances.

Comment: @Caduchon I have added an alternative solution covering this.